# 50Hz "noise" on power or ground line of power supply

Tags: power-supply, noise, oscilloscope

I have a power supply that creates a 50Hz sine wave when I connect my oscilloscope to it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fezFuq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

This sine wave looks like this below.

[image]

[image]

Question:

Why I am getting a sine wave shown on the scope with a 50Hz frequency when the PSU is not connected to the mains?

I did not connect the Ground end of the probe to the negative. However, when I do the sine wave goes away. But why is there even a 50Hz sine wave in the first place?

Comment: You must ground your oscilloscope or you will pick up random em fields in the vicinity

Comment: Try this experiment: (1) Set your probe to **10X**. (2) Grab tightly the probe's tip, with its GND floating. (3) Observe 50 Hz wave amplitude on the 'scope.

Comment: There is a loop somewhere, since you are measuring electric fields. How big do you suppose that loop is? It might go all the way back to your circuit breaker box and back. Magnetic field induces a current proportional to loop area.

Comment: Y capacitor leakage. What's your grounding situation?

Comment: Touch the probe tip with a finger. Don't ground yourself or touch scope ground lead. Do you see same 50 Hz signal?

Comment: @Justme yes I do see the 50Hz sine wave. How do I get rid of it. My oscilloscope is at least 1m from the maains supply cable.

Comment: This a good question to examine Common mode noise in high impedance with good ground connections. try my experiments. If nothing works, use a big RF cap from floating ground to PE ground.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 please see how I am applying this is this post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621294/tida-ref-design-produces-a-50hz-signal-on-output

Comment: You can't get rid of it if you keep floating your object you probe. Any floating object that has no connection to any fixed potential will pick up mains hum from surroundings and it can be seen on scope. You must connect scope probe ground lead to your circuit common ground to fix it. Besides without probe ground lead you can't make measurements as scope will measure voltage between scope tip and scope ground so it can't measure floating objects.

Comment: @Justme Please see the application part of this question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621294/tida-ref-design-produces-a-50hz-signal-on-output

Answer (score 2):

E-fields are generated by high impedance unbalanced inductive lines and picked up by the same.

The zero-crossing flat spot is due to non-linear low impedance of PSU drivers at zero crossing effects on attenuation of E-field. The noise can be AM radio signals or The >5th harmonics are due to its transformer effects from SMPS inside scope creating common mode noise.The probe is looking at an antenna effectively the noise can be traced easily by impedance loading effects (f) with high impedance loads to scope signal gnd.

Try 100k then try 100 to 1000 pF to sig gnd. Report findings.
Then try a 1m wire on x1 probe and measure alone.

Your 2m body is an E-field antenna that can pick up far more than a little PSU. With a 10M probe tip only you can pick up >50 V , with 1M something different. That depends on the stray impedance coupling between the emitters ( line wires ) and the detector ( a floating supply with wire pairs) or your floating ungrounded body.

Do some experiments to determine what that stray impedance is and path length of unbalanced line pair.  A large wire loop is more unbalanced that a twisted pair.  Neutral is close to Ground impedance and voltage so this further unbalances stray E-fields for low frequency EMI with 2 conductors vs 1 line and about 1uH /m inductance.

When the wire pair is twisted, the inductance cancels somewhat leaving a smaller emitted signal. when just parallel wires, the capacitance reduces and the radiated levels increase at near field but at far field makes less difference.

But even at far field the elevation of line distribution towers still swap 2 phases every kilometer to null the effects of unbalanced impedance floating to ground from the EH field magnetosphere wobble due to solar flares that induce high currents and voltage called the Carrington Effect.

- take a drive on your country roads and tell me if different.

Comment: "Try 100k then try 100 to 1000 pF to sig gnd. Report findings" so 100k capacitor?

Comment: No 100k resistor to measure 1V stray signal impedanceONLY not for actual use.  This helps identify the cause.